# Ошибка php Uncaught Error

Tags: php

Использую функцию `xmlrpc_encode()`. Вот код:

```
$data=xmlrpc_encode(static::$data);
fwrite($file,$data);
```

Вот ошибка:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   FileConverter\ParsingFile\XML\xmlrpc_encode() in
>   /var/www/html/php-oop-file-converter-Kushnerevich-master/src/ParsingFile/XML/XmlFileConverter.php:25

читал, что может быть с устаревшей функцией, но в документации есть версия 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `xmlrpc_encode()` относится к пакету [XML-RPC](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlrpc.php), который не входит в стандартный набор - [нужно устанавливать](http://php.net/manual/ru/xmlrpc.installation.php). Кроме того функция [экспериментальная](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.xmlrpc-encode.php). Может поискать на github библиотеку какую-нибудь для ваших целей?

Для уставновки на Windows следует раскомментировать (убрать `;` в начале) строку в `php.ini`

```
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Если хостер не предоставляет этот пакет, то ищите библиотеку.